# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ....utils.HibernateSessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

help me, please. If I run it on the psvm class Session works perfect. But when it run in tomcat: tomcat display this exception.

**Tomcat exception:**  Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.haki.utils.HibernateSessionFactory

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Haki</groupId>
  <artifactId>CRUD</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>CRUD Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <hibernate-version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate-version>
    <spring-version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--driver for connection to MySQL-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>CRUD</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>-->

    <mapping class="ru.haki.domain.User"/>

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**HibernateSessionFactory**

```
package ru.haki.utils;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateSessionFactory {

   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void closeSession(Session session) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**User**

```
package ru.haki.domain;

//import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "", catalog = "test")
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private boolean isAdmin;
    private Date createdDate;

    public User() {
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }

    public User(String name, Integer age, boolean isAdmin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
        this.createdDate = new Date();
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 25)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "age", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "isAdmin", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean admin) {
        isAdmin = admin;
    }


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "createdDate", nullable = false)
    public java.util.Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (id != user.id) return false;
        if (isAdmin != user.isAdmin) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(user.name) : user.name != null) return false;
        if (age != null ? !age.equals(user.age) : user.age != null) return false;
        if (createdDate != null ? !createdDate.equals(user.createdDate) : user.createdDate != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (age != null ? age.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (isAdmin ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (createdDate != null ? createdDate.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", isAdmin=" + isAdmin +
                ", createdDate=" + createdDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you install this application under tomcat? Looks like broken build of war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by deleting Hibernate Annotations dependency because they are included in core.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the hibernate jars inside the tomcat library as well. **NoClassDefFoundError** mostly occurs when jar is missing.

Comment: if you look to pom file it has hibernate dependencies